# Android app wont run if my array is a certain length

Tags: java, android, arrays

The app I am creating has lots of pictures that the user will be able to scroll through, In the app there is an array of objects and each object contains a picture and a statistic. My app was running perfectly is my array would only contain 58 objects, however now when I build the app quits and bring up the error "Sorry, your application has stopped unexpectedly" and tho LogCat shows

```
10-25 18:46:24.578: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 18:46:24.578: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notes/com.example.notes.NotesListActivity}:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

and here is my current code

```
public class NotesListActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

public boolean nextClicked = false;
public boolean prevClicked = false;
public int counter = 1;
public int nextImg;
public FunnyPic[] picArray = new FunnyPic[55];
{
    picArray[0] = new FunnyPic(R.raw.img1, 0);
    picArray[1] = new FunnyPic(R.raw.img2, 0);
    .....
    .....
    .....
    picArray[180] = new FunnyPic(R.raw.img181, 0);
    picArray[181] = new FunnyPic(R.raw.img182, 0);

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button changePicButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    changePicButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    Log.i("onClick", "BEGIN");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if(counter == picArray.length-1)
        counter=0;
    image.setImageResource(picArray[counter].getImg());
    counter++;
    Log.i("onClick", "END");
}

public void prevPicHandler(View traget)
{
    if(counter==0)
    {
        counter = picArray.length-1;
    }
    counter--;
    Log.i("onClick", "BEGIN");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(picArray[counter].getImg());

    Log.i("onClick", "END");
}




}
```

please let me know if you have any suggestions. Also if anyone could recommend a more efficient way to put the objects into the array so I wont have to manually put them in each time I add new pictures.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an array with 55 elements:

```
public FunnyPic[] picArray = new FunnyPic[55];
```

The maximum valid index here is 54.

You're then trying to access element 181:

```
picArray[181] = new FunnyPic(R.raw.img182, 0);
```

How did you expect that to work? Have you considered using a `List<FunnyPic>` instead?

Note that you've got an array variable declaration statement, and then separately an initializer block. You *don't* have an array initializer. If that's what you thought you had, you should have used:

```
public FunnyPic[] picArray =
{
    new FunnyPic(R.raw.img1, 0),
    new FunnyPic(R.raw.img2, 0),
    ...
    new FunnyPic(R.raw.img182, 0)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your max index is `54`, yet in the sample code, you're accessing indices greater than that. Hm..I wonder what the problem could be!?

---

## Cat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the FunnyPic objects in an ArrayList or Vector?

```
public ArrayList<FunnyPic> getFunnyPicArray()
{
    ArrayList<FunnyPic> picList = new ArrayList<FunnyPic>();
    picList.add(new FunnyPic(R.raw.img1, 0));
    //..
    return picList;
}
```